# how do I stay in the selected tab during a postback by jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tabs

I have following jquery to set the selected tab as active tab, but it is not quite working. Can anybody help me out there? Basically I used a hidden field to save the selected tab, and in the ready function I set it to active.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var tab = $get('selected_tab').value;

            //When page loads...
            $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
            $("ul.tabs li:tab").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
            $(".tab_content:tab").show(); //Show first tab content

            //On Click Event
            $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

                $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
                $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
                $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

                var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
                $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
                return false;
            });

        });
  </script>  

<div id="content">
 <input typE="hidden" id="selected_tab" name="selected_tab" value="0" />
 <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1" onclick="document.getElementById('selected_tab').value=0;">Details</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#tab2" onclick="document.getElementById('selected_tab').value=1;">History</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#attachmentcontent" onclick="document.getElementById('selected_tab').value=2;">Attachments</a></li> 
    </ul>
```

Comment: Check this link http://forums.asp.net/p/1599404/4064850.aspx

Comment: how do I do that? The only answer I am happy with is the one for regular expression. I haven't got any good answers for any of my other questions yet.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set the value of the selected_tab in your server code, then show the tab[selected_tab_value] on document.ready

ascx

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="selected_tab" name="selected_tab" />
```

ascx.cs

```
int selectedtab = 5;
selected_tab.value = selectedtab.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. In the tab3, I have couple of controls will cause a postback, should I set the selected_tab in all the controls events or I could just put it in the page_load?

Comment: Just put it in the page_load, that should work just fine i guess. The page_load get's called on every postback, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: How do I use the value from the hidden field in the jquery? Thanks

Comment: $('selected_tab').val() to get it and $('selected_tab').val("NewValue") to set it, remember it's a string!
If my answer was helpful please mark it as an answer..